# Correlation and coefficient

Tags: javascript

Currently I am reading Eloquent Js book and at chapter 4.The topic involved computing correlation is confusing to me.How important correlation and coefficient in real word programming.Could someone who have read this book explain me in details.Below is the code that I want to know  how it is working.
What is doing table[index]+=1?And why index+=1,+=2 and not +=3,+=4 etc.

```
function tableFor(event, journal) {

  let table = [0, 0, 0, 0];

  for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {

    let entry = journal[i],
        index = 0;

    if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }

  return table;

}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

Comment: Can you please Edit your Title and make your question easier to read? thank you!

Comment: For each entry in the journal, if the entry does not have a `"pizza"` event and does not have a truthy value for `squirrel`, the *first* `0` in table is incremented. If it has a `pizza` event, the *second* `0` in `table` is incremented. If `squirrel`, then the *third*. If both pizza event *and* squirrel, the fourth.

Comment: And I am wondering to know that why there is a events?

Comment: Adding for @Tyler:  `table[index] += 1;` counting  the number of time the combination describe appears in the JOURNAL

Comment: @HrantBaloyan I don't understand the question. To answer this from your question: *"why index+=1,+=2 and not +=3,+=4 etc."*. The `table` array only has four items. Indexes start from `0`, so the last index in your array is `3`. If you did `table[4]` (or anything greater than `4`), you would get an error because no such item exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `table[index]+=1` same as `table[index] = table[index] + 1;`.
The `index+=1` same as `index = index + 1;`